# Inner content showing then disappearing in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

My issue is related to a `JScrollPane` with an inner `JPanel`. I try to draw on the `JPanel` but it very briefly appears then disappears until I manually move the `HorizontalScrollBar`, then appears again and stay stable. To avoid the manual intervention (or an `HorizontalScrollBar.setValue` that would be hardly manageable in the actual code) I unsuccessfully tried `validate/revalidate` (and more) on the `JPanel`, the `Viewport`, the `JScrollPane` and the `JFrame`.

The (very) simplified code hereunder reproduce the issue. Probably something obvious but I can't see it.

```
public class Main {

private JFrame mainPane;

private RenderZone renderZone = new RenderZone();
private JScrollPane renderScrollPane = new JScrollPane(renderZone,
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, 
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);



public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main window = new Main();
                window.mainPane.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Main() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    mainPane = new JFrame();
    mainPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
    mainPane.setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
    mainPane.setLocation(new Point(200, 200));
    mainPane.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, renderScrollPane, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, mainPane.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, renderScrollPane, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, mainPane.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, renderScrollPane, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, mainPane.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, renderScrollPane, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, mainPane.getContentPane());
    mainPane.getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout);
    mainPane.getContentPane().add(renderScrollPane);

}

public class RenderZone extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8240875812801921009L;

    private BufferedImage image = null;
    private BufferedImage sub = null;

    public RenderZone() {
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1124, 768));// added 100 for test purpose
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);// pour repeindre la panel à chaque fois
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();
        if(image==null) {

            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(RenderZone.class.getResourceAsStream("TestImage0.png"));
                sub = image.getSubimage(0, 0, 1024, 768);
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }

        if( sub!=null)g2.drawImage(sub, 0, 0, null); 
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with the code, here is the fixed code. For explanations, see the points below the code.

```
public class RenderZone extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8240875812801921009L;

    private BufferedImage image = null;
    private BufferedImage sub = null;

    public RenderZone() {
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1124, 768));// added 100 for test purpose
        image = new BufferedImage(2000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        sub = image.getSubimage(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);// pour repeindre la panel à chaque fois
        if (sub != null) {
            g.drawImage(sub, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```

OK..

1. `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();` Hard to determine why you thought that was a good idea, when you already had a valid `Graphics` instance. But basically, use the `Graphics` instance provided.
2. `ImageIO.read(..);` Reading an image is **not** something that should be done in any paint method. It should be loaded in the constructor of the class, just once.
3. `sub = image.getSubimage(0, 0, 1024, 768);` Again, not something you want to be doing every time paint is called, and in fact, it'd be more optimal to  create the image at the right size in photo editing software, and just load the **cropped** image.
4. `} catch (IOException e) {}` Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`
5. `if( sub!=null)g2.drawImage(sub, 0, 0, null);` Since every `JComponent` **is an** `ImageObserver`, it should be
   `if( sub!=null)g2.drawImage(sub, 0, 0, this);`

And some things that are suspect but which were not part of the immediate problem, so they were unchanged:

1. `// pour repeindre la panel à chaque fois` What was the point of that code comment (intended for human consumption only) in .. French? Please put code comments (for this site) in English. Otherwise they are noise.
2. `this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1124, 768));` probably best to override the `getPreferredSize()` and return a value based on the size of (as in numbers obtained directly from) the `sub` image.
3. `mainPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));` this is better as `mainPane.pack();`. The latter is not guesswork, and will account for the preferred size of the child components.

Comment: Tanks a lot!! It works. For the records, please note that the faulty part was the Graphics2D g2. Using regular graphics solved the issue without changing anything else. Now I'll have to create multiline with thickness  somewhere else in the code (this part was remove from the simplfied version). Anyway, that's great. Thanks again (I can also say it in multiple noisy ways ;-))